# How to keep the current state in a PINE script?

Tags: pine-script

I'm developing an indicator for opening and closing long positions with a PINE script.

The triangle means open and the cross means close.

The condition to be judged as close may occur multiple times, and the closed mark is displayed even if it is not open.

[image]

Is there a way to keep the "open" state?

My script:

```
//@version=4
study(title="My Script", shorttitle="My Script", overlay=true, resolution="")

cond_long_open = // same condition
cond_long_close = // same condition
plotshape(cond_long_open , style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green)
plotshape(cond_long_close, style=shape.xcross, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the var keyword to initialize variables only once.

```
var bool cond_long_open = false
var bool cond_long_close = false

if long
    cond_long_open := true
```

Something like that.

Comment: What does a ":" mean? I read the documentation but didn't understand. What does the code look like in other languages such as js? Thanks.

Comment: Consider := one operator, not a ':' plus an equals. It is simply a reassignment operator. In this context, it might be similar to calling a global keyword in Python, as if you don't use it in the if block, it will consider cond_long_open a new variable in that scope.

Basically, if you are changing the value declared with the var keyword, or changing a variable within the same bar execution, use that operator. Use it if you are not iniitializing a new variable.